# If $X,Y$ are two independent random variables how can you calculate $\mathbb{E}[e^{XY}]$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables where $X$ is standard normal distributed and $Y$ is distributed as $P(Y=1)=P(Y=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$  how can one calculate $\mathbb{E}[e^{XY}]$? I don't see how to use the joinst density of $X,Y$ to find the expectation (since one is continious and the other is discrete). I also don't see how I can factor the density since we dont have $\mathbb{E}[f(X)g(Y)]=\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]$ but rather $\mathbb{E}[h(X,Y)]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Z=XY$ is still a standard normal, thus $\mathbb{E}[e^Z]$ is a [lognormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)...

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{XY}]=\sqrt{e}$$

EDIT: to derive that $Z=XY\sim \Phi$ just observe that if $Z=-X$ you get

$$f_Z(z)=f_X(-z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! One follow up question, why is $Z=XY$ still normal?

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising $P(Z\le z)=\tfrac12P(X\le z)+\tfrac12P(X\ge-z)=P(X\le z)$.

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising : added some details

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big[e^{XY}\big]&= \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[e^{XY}\big|Y\right]\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{XY}\big|Y=-1\right]+ \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{XY}\big|Y=1\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-X}\right]+ \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{X}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\big(e^{-x}+e^x\big)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^\frac{1}{2}\big(e^{-\frac{(x+1)^2}{2}}+e^{-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}}\big)dx\\
&=e^\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: ?? $E[e^{-X}]=E[e^{X}]=\sqrt{e}$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error.